# postgres_exporter SSL is not enabled on the server

Tags: postgresql, prometheus-postgres-exporter

I try to run postgres_exporter version 0.12.0 on my linux machine. And cant figured out the reason of error "SSL is not enabled on the server". Because I already set sslmode = disable.
Here is example of my postgres_exporter.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Prometheus PostgreSQL Exporter
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
User=postgres
Group=postgres
Environment=DATA_SOURCE_NAME="user=postgres host=/var/run/postgresql/ sslmode=disable"
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/postgres_exporter --config.file=/usr/local/bin/postgres_exporter.yml --log.level=debug

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And my postgres_exporter.yml:

```
auth_modules:
  foo1: # Set this to any name you want
    type: userpass
    userpass:
        username: postgres
        password: postgres
    options:
        sslmode: disable
```

So the sslmode is disable, but I get error:
caller=postgres_exporter.go:716 level=error err="Error opening connection to database (%22user=postgres): pq: SSL is not enabled on the server"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution: You need to pass `DATA_SOURCE_NAME` clearly without quotation marks, otherwise it can’t read `DATA_SOURCE_NAME` and uses default params instead where `sslmode` is not disabled.

```
Environment=DATA_SOURCE_NAME=postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable
```